# Executing Dynamic Native SQL with Oracle Table type using IN operator gives invalid identifier error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamicquery

In the procedure, final sql statement which is printing in my console is correct and when you run this as a static sql statement inside procedure it runs without any error. But inside the dynamic sql it fails.

I tried executing using DYNAMIC_SQL package, but it results in same error. Also, I tried giving it as a bind variable for 'table(testCodes)'. That also failed. Tags oracleplsqldynamicquerystored-procedures suggested tags:oracle Your question couldn't be submitted.

```
create or replace TYPE "INPUTCODE" as object (pc varchar2(100) )

create or replace TYPE "INPUTCODEARR" IS TABLE OF inputcode;

create or replace PROCEDURE "TEST_PROC" (
            testCodes IN inputcodeArr, 
            timeHorizon IN NUMBER, 
            p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS var_sqlStmt VARCHAR2(4096); 
BEGIN 
   var_sqlStmt := 'select t.a,t.b, t.c'; 
   var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || 'from test t';
   if testCodes is not null then 
      var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || ', table(testCodes) tc'; 
      var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || 'where tc.pc = t.name'; 
   end if; 
   dbms_output.put_line('Final SQL Statement::' || var_sqlStmt); 
   open p_recordset for var_sqlStmt; 
END TEST_PROC;
```

Comment: Please answer my questions

Comment: Try USING clause and a bind variable: `var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || ', table(:x) tc';` and `open p_recordset for var_sqlStmt USING testCodes;`

Comment: That's because local variable is invisible from inside dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

Like kordirko suggested, you need to bind the variable; not as the whole table operator, but as `table(:x)`.  Here's a full example in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> create or replace type inputcode as object (pc varchar2(100));
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type inputcodearr is table of inputcode;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table test(a number, b number, c number, name varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1,2,3,'A');

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace procedure test_proc(
  2     testcodes in inputcodearr,
  3     p_recordset in out sys_refcursor
  4  ) is
  5  begin
  6     open p_recordset for
  7     '
  8             select t.a, t.b, t.c
  9             from test t, table(:input) tc
 10             where tc.pc = t.name
 11     '
 12     using testcodes;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> variable my_refcursor refcursor;
SQL> exec test_proc(inputcodeArr(inputcode('A'), inputcode('B')), :my_refcursor);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print my_refcursor;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var_sqlStmt := 'select t.a,t.b, t.c'; 
var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || ' from test t';
if testCodes is not null then 
    var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || ', table('||testCodes||') tc';
var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || ' where tc.pc = t.name';
```

This should work.